Open Reading Frame problem
Problem
An mRNA of 999 bases codes for a protein with 300 amino acids and the open reading frame (ORF) starts from base 38. If the base at position 903 is deleted the length of the ORF increases by 3 bases. Which base is present at position 942 of the original mRNA?
a) A
b) U
c) G or A
d) Cor U
My reasoning
Since the ORF starts from the 38th base, the first 37 bases form the promoter sequence. Further, since there are 300 amino acids, the orf would have 900 (+3 +3) bases including the start codon AUG and stop codon, UAA/UAG/UGA.
Therefore the ORF would be 906 bases long, from the 38th base to the 943rd base.
So, the codons, (38,39,40), (41, 42,43),...., (902,903,904),..., (941, 942,943) code for amino acids.
If the base at the 903rd position were deleted, there would be a frameshift mutation, and all the bases after 903rd place would shift leftward by 1 place.
I do not understand how this leads to the increase of the length of the ORF by 3 bases.
Because, the deletion of 1 base would cause the length of the ORF to change by 1,4,7,... bases, but not by 3 bases.

The mistake in the original poster’s reasoning is to calculate the ORF as 906 bases. In fact, as normally defined, it is 903 bases — the amino-acid coding portion (300 x 3 = 900 bases) plus the termination codon (3 bases).
The initiation codon (normally AUG) encodes the amino acid, methionine!
Hence the end of the ORF is at base 940 (37 + 903) — the termination codon consists of bases 938–940.
We are concerned with the base 942, at a position +2 from the termination codon, and this will change to position +1 (941) after a single base deletion that abolishes the normal termination codon.
For the original bases 942–944 to become the new termination codon 941–943 (as the increase in ORF requires) this region must become a termination codon UAA, UAG or UGA — in each case starting with ‘U’ at new position 941.
So the answer is (b).
NB
Bases 1–37 are not the mRNA equivalent of the DNA promoter, which is not transcribed. They have a function in their own right, and are referred to as the 5' untranslated region of the mRNA.
